# Polymer CLI build runs out of memory

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-cli

I am quite surprised, when I run `polymer build` after implementing more components, it runs out of memory. How isit possible? I won't consider my site/app very big yet ...

```
info:    Building application...
info:    Generating build/unbundled...
info:    Generating build/bundled...

<--- Last few GCs --->

  105411 ms: Mark-sweep 1343.6 (1434.7) -> 1343.0 (1434.7) MB, 1430.6 / 0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
  106857 ms: Mark-sweep 1343.0 (1434.7) -> 1343.0 (1434.7) MB, 1446.6 / 0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
  108349 ms: Mark-sweep 1343.0 (1434.7) -> 1343.0 (1434.7) MB, 1491.5 / 0 ms [last resort gc].
  109808 ms: Mark-sweep 1343.0 (1434.7) -> 1342.6 (1434.7) MB, 1459.5 / 0 ms [last resort gc].


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x24b44a0c9e31 <JS Object>
    2: nextToken [/Users/limjiewmeng/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:~2459] [pc=0x313c0f47bb3b] (this=0x3618e7c0f981 <a Parser with map 0x18a29db9aa01>)
    3: next [/Users/limjiewmeng/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2413] [pc=0x313c0ee10d47] (this=0x3618e7c0f981 <a Parser with map 0x...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [/Users/limjiewmeng/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/bin/node]
 2: node::FatalException(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Message>) [/Users/limjiewmeng/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/bin/node]
 3: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [/Users/limjiewmeng/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/bin/node]
 4: v8::internal::Factory::NewFixedArray(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [/Users/limjiewmeng/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/bin/node]
 5: v8::internal::FullCodeGenerator::PopulateDeoptimizationData(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Code>) [/Users/limjiewmeng/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/bin/node]
 6: v8::internal::FullCodeGenerator::MakeCode(v8::internal::CompilationInfo*) [/Users/limjiewmeng/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/bin/node]
 7: v8::internal::Compiler::EnsureDeoptimizationSupport(v8::internal::CompilationInfo*) [/Users/limjiewmeng/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/bin/node]
 8: v8::internal::OptimizedCompileJob::CreateGraph() [/Users/limjiewmeng/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/bin/node]
 9: v8::internal::Compiler::GetOptimizedCode(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSFunction>, v8::internal::Compiler::ConcurrencyMode, v8::internal::BailoutId, v8::internal::JavaScriptFrame*) [/Users/limjiewmeng/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/bin/node]
10: v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::CompileOptimized(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSFunction>, v8::internal::Compiler::ConcurrencyMode) [/Users/limjiewmeng/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/bin/node]
11: v8::internal::Runtime_CompileOptimized_Concurrent(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/Users/limjiewmeng/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/bin/node]
12: 0x313c0e50961b
13: 0x313c0e538279
[1]    8057 abort      polymer build
```

Running in verbose mode gave me some clues:

```
debug:   accept: bower_components/iron-behaviors/iron-control-state.html
debug:   accept: bower_components/paper-ripple/paper-ripple.html
debug:   accept: bower_components/paper-styles/color.html
debug:   accept: bower_components/iron-a11y-keys-behavior/iron-a11y-keys-behavior.html
debug:   accept: bower_components/iron-behaviors/iron-control-state.html
debug:   accept: bower_components/paper-ripple/paper-ripple.html
debug:   accept: bower_components/paper-styles/color.html
debug:   accept: bower_components/iron-a11y-keys-behavior/iron-a11y-keys-behavior.html
debug:   accept: bower_components/iron-behaviors/iron-control-state.html
debug:   accept: bower_components/paper-ripple/paper-ripple.html
debug:   accept: bower_components/paper-styles/color.html
debug:   accept: bower_components/iron-a11y-keys-behavior/iron-a11y-keys-behavior.html
```

Seems like its running in loops?

**UPDATE**

I notice if I remove some components from `polymer.json`, it will build but its not really what I want?

**UPDATE 2: Possible Workaround**

Don't fragment everything. Inline some imports. Think its works around the issue as the build tool is more likely to find similar dependencies in the "larger" bundles and be able to group them together. Instead of having to include them in all bundles.

Comment: maybe worth filing a issue on [polymer-build](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-build)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so that I can close this.

It seems like the problem was with creating too many bundles. So instead of loading (nearly) every single component dynamically, which I later learnt is likely not a good idea anyway, I start to group similar things together to include in a bundle. This solved this issue for me.

Comment: how to increase --max-old-space-size in polymer ??since we don't have package.json where we can set memory size?